# conditional addFields to embedded objects in MongoDb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am trying to add in values to a list of embedded objects based on another value within the object. A sample document looks like:

```
{ 
    "array" : [{
        "val1" : "a"
    }, {
        "val1" : "b"
    }]
}
```

What I am trying to achieve is

```
{ 
    "array" : [{
        "val1" : "a",
        "isVal1A": true
    }, {
        "val1" : "b",
        "isVal1A": false
    }]
}
```

How do I go about doing this using an aggregate pipeline? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try
[Live version](https://mongoplayground.net/p/wgcqtQt2IeW)

```
db.collection.aggregate({
  $addFields: {
    array: {
      $map: {
        input: "$array",
        as: "a",
        in: {
          $cond: [
            {
              $eq: [
                "$$a.val1",
                "a"
              ]
            },
            {
              "$mergeObjects": [
                "$$a",
                {
                  "Isval1A": true
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "$mergeObjects": [
                "$$a",
                {
                  "Isval1A": false
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: this seems to be giving false for all

Comment: Updating the condition to be `$$a.val1` instead of `$val1` works! Thanks @Minsky

Comment: oops, good catch, yes. Will fix that now...feel free to accept if it works @aakashgupta.0205

Answer (score 0):

You can try,

- `$map` to iterate loop of `array`, check condition if `val1` is 'a' then returnb true otherwise false, `$mergeObjects` to merge current object and status field

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      array: {
        $map: {
          input: "$array",
          in: {
            $mergeObjects: [
              "$$this",
              {
                isVal1A: {
                  $cond: [{ $eq: ["$$this.val1", "a"] }, true, false]
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/jbrP79ZzK4q)